# connecting back end to front end

Tags: java, api, frontend, backend

I'm a newcomer to backend (and to Stackoverflow so forgive me if this is a stupid question) and i have coded a User login and registration application with email verification in JAVA. I also have a complete frontend webdesign with html, css and JavaScript. Now my question is is there a way to link my back end to the frontend so i can use my login features for my website like for example how you link the css in a `index.html`? I'm using Springboot as my framework and psql for my DB. I don't know if I have an API or if i have inadvertently used one but my postman doesnt give me errors when i give it POST or GET requests.

Comment: Have you looked online for any help? Spring Boot is rather easy to setup. [spring.io](https://spring.io) has plenty of information. I suggest you explore their tutorial section, as they discuss how to serve web content, integrate thymeleaf, handle form submissions, etc.

Comment: You're probably using PostgreSQL for the database. Psql is a command-line utility that is used to test and administer PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Jakarta Servlet

The usual route for a web app with Java is using [*Jakarta Servlet*](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/) and [*Jakarta Server Pages (JSP)*](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/pages/) technologies. You may also find useful any of [many other](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/) "enterprise edition" frameworks that are largely aimed at web apps and web services in the joint cooperative effort known as [Jakarta EE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jakarta_EE). (Formerly known as Java EE.)

You can code servlets and JSPs by hand. Or you can choose from any of several templating frameworks built on top of those.

Alternately, and my favorite, is to use [*Vaadin Flow*](https://vaadin.com/flow). In this framework you write plain pure Java to build your forms in terms of widgets such as buttons, fields, and so on, with little to no awareness of Web technologies. At runtime, the necessary HTML, CSS, and JavaScript are automatically generated so as to render your user-interface remotely in the web browser. Under the covers, Vaadin Flow is actually a large Servlet, pre-written for our benefit. Vaadin Flow works with or without Spring Boot, your choice.

By the way, an alternative to web browser clients is to build a local client app that talks to your Java-based server via [sockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_socket), [Web Services](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service), [Java RMI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_remote_method_invocation), or other avenues. Such client can be written in Java via [JavaFX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaFX)/[OpenJFX](https://openjfx.io/), [Swing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swing_(Java)), or [SWT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Widget_Toolkit). Or use other languages/toolkits outside Java.

Explaining any of these technologies is much too broad for Stack Overflow. You'll need to do some deep dives into researching these to decide what works for you. I suggest starting with [a search of Wikipedia](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=site%3Awikipedia.org%20java%20web%20app%20frameworks&t=osx&ia=web).

For specific software recommendations, see the sister site, [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

---

FYI, [*psql*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL#psql) is not a database. You may be referring to the [*Postgres*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL) database server, for which *psql* is one of several client tools for interactive [console sessions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Console_application). [*DataGrip*](https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/) is another such database client tool, for example.

Comment: thank you! I knew the question would need a broad answer but this pretty much sums it up for me!